# Groovy map, get, variable, Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a problem with mapping in Groovy.
I would like to get a value based on a variable.

```
def function(){
    map = [
         'test1': '1234',
         'test2': '4567'
    ]
    var=test1
    def result = map.get.("$var")
    return result
}
```

But, unfortunately. I always get back:

> Cannot get property '[test1]' on null object

Comment: it's not a valid groovy code

Comment: The `test1` on line 6 needs to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a HashMap behind the scenes here and the way you are accessing it `map.get.["$var"]` Groovy is trying to access a key called "get" on your variable map.

You just want `map[var]`

- Updated with BalRog's note below

Comment: Or even just `map[var]`.